# Treating rows of buttons independently for button:focus

Tags: html, css

I'm new to python/flask, and have made a simple app which collects user input for 5 variables, and display an output that's dependant on the combination of those six variables. I've made a simple webpage with the following code to collect the user's input via clickable buttons:

```js
function setValue(inputId, value, button) {
  document.getElementById(inputId + '_input').value = value;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 35em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.button {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  background-position: 0 90%;
  background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
  background-size: 4px 3px;
  border-radius: 15px 225px 255px 15px 15px 255px 225px 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 15px 28px 25px -18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #41403e;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Neucha, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 23px;
  outline: none;
  padding: .75rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 235ms ease-in-out;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 255px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 225px 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 255px 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px 225px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 2px 8px 8px -5px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 2px, 0);
}

.button:focus {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 2px 8px 4px -6px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Rhesus Genotype Analyzer</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/">
  <label for="D">D:</label>

  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('D', 'pos', this)">Pos</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('D', 'neg', this)">Neg</button>
  

  <label for="C">C:</label>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('C', 'pos', this)">Pos</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('C', 'neg', this)">Neg</button>
  <br><br>

  <label for="E">E:</label>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('E', 'pos', this)">Pos</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('E', 'neg', this)">Neg</button>
  <br><br>

  <label for="c">c:</label>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('c', 'pos', this)">Pos</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('c', 'neg', this)">Neg</button>
  <br><br>

  <label for="e">e:</label>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('e', 'pos', this)">Pos</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('e', 'neg', this)">Neg</button>
  <br><br>

  <input type="hidden" id="D_input" name="D">
  <input type="hidden" id="C_input" name="C">
  <input type="hidden" id="E_input" name="E">
  <input type="hidden" id="c_input" name="c">
  <input type="hidden" id="e_input" name="e">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The issue I have is that only one of the 10 buttons displays the 'focus' state. Is it possible to treat each row of buttons independently? I.e., allow the 'D' pos or neg button to be 'focused', and allow the 'E' pos or neg to be 'focused' too, so that the user can see what they've selected?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: @DavidThomas, not required to retain any of it. I'm grateful of any additions or edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows, though this answer is reliant on the `:has()` CSS pseudo-class function, though this is – *now* – well supported in modern browsers, this approach may mean you'll need to use JavaScript depending on the browsers employed by your users.

That said, the following meets your needs (I think) and uses only HTML and CSS to do so; explanatory comments are in the code:

```css
/*
  a simple reset, in which I ensure that all elements are sized
  in the same way, following the border-box algorithm which
  includes assigned padding, margins, and border-width within
  the assigned size of the element. I'm also setting the font
  of the document to remove browser defaults:
*/
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* forcing the <html> element to occupy the full size of the
   viewport's block-axis (the axis upon which 'blocks' are
   positioned according to the language choice of the user): */
html {
  block-size: 100%;
}

/* defining some custom properties to help lay out the contents,
   and its spacing: */
body {
  --space-s: calc(var(--space) * 0.5);
  --space: 0.5rem;
  --space-l: calc(var(--space) * 2);
  /* 1vb is 1% of the element's size on the block-axis, therefore
     this rule sizes the body to take up the full size of the
     viewport: */
  min-block-size: 100vb;
  /* setting the padding of the element, using the CSS var()
     function along with the defined CSS custom property: */
  padding: var(--space-l);
}

main {
  /* as above, sizing the block-axis of the element to take 100%
     of the available space: */
  min-block-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  padding: var(--space-l);
}

h1 {
  /* styling the font of the <h1> after forcing all
     fonts (earlier) to be only 1rem, here we double
     that size to emphasise the heading: */
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* setting a margin on the block-end (the side of
     the element that would be nearest the next block-
     level sibling element) to be in proportion to
     the font-size of the current element: */
  margin-block-end: 0.5em;
}

h2::after {
  content: ':';
}

form {
  /* using grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* setting the gap between adjacent elements within
     the grid: */
  gap: var(--space-l);
}

/* styling any <button> element within any <form> that
   has any :invalid form-elements (<input>, <textarea>...): */
form:has(:invalid) button {
  /* highlighting that clicking the button is disallowed: */
  cursor: not-allowed;
  /* reducing the opacity to imply that the element is
     disabled: */
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* it would have been possible to use:
        pointer-events: none;
     but unfortunately that prevents the :hover pseudo-class
     from matching, which means the cursor wouldn't be
     changed. This is the choice I made, you may feel
     that preventing user-action on the <button> is worth
     that limitation. */
}

fieldset {
  --indicator: hsl(0deg 60% 40% / 0.8);
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: var(--space-l);
  isolation: isolate;
  padding-block: var(--space);
  padding-inline: var(--space-l);
  position: relative;
}

fieldset::after {
  /* I freely admit I went a bit overboard...
     here we're using a linear-gradient as a background image,
     the gradient running 90degrees (to the right, 0degrees is
     vertical), we have transparent from 0 running to 70% of the
     background-size, after which we use the colour assigned to
     the custom CSS property --indicator or, if that property isn't
     defined, the default colour of transparent.
     The background is positioned at 100% (x-axis) and 50% (y-axis),
     and sized 100% in both horizontal and vertical axes (respectively),
     and we set no-repeat so that the image doesn't repeat: */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0 70%, var(--indicator, transparent)) 100% 50% / 100% 100% no-repeat;
  /* to occlude the error gradient we use the clip-path, which allows
     us to limit the visibility of the element according to the
     shape we define. We're using the polygon() function here,
     which takes a list of comma-separated positions (for x and y
     respectively), to define a number of points; within the space
     formed by those points the content is visible. Outside, the
     content is hidden ('clipped'): */
  clip-path:
    polygon(
      100% 0,
      100% 0,
      100% 100%,
      100% 100%
    );
  /* content is a mandatory property to have the pseudo-element
     be rendered, an empty string is valid 'content' for this: */
  content: '';
  /* using inset to specify the position of the pseudo-element in
     reference to its containing block, here it's positioned 0
     distance from each edge (top, right, bottom, left respectively)
   */
  inset: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /* we're transitioning the clip-path property, over 500ms and
     with a linear easing function: */
  transition: clip-path 500ms linear;
  /* to position the pseudo-element behind all content of its
     containing block ancestor, appearing in front of only
     that element's background: */
  z-index: -1;
}

/* styling the ::after pseudo-element of any <fieldset> that contains
   a :user-invalid form-element: */
fieldset:has(:user-invalid)::after {
  clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

label {
  /* using a non-'static' (the default) value for the
     position property, in order that this element becomes
     the containing block for its descendants: */
  position: relative;
}

/* the element that contains the text associated with each
   <input> element: */
.labelText {
  /* various CSS custom properties: */
  --base-h: 0deg;
  --base-s: 20%;
  --base-l: 30%;
  --base-z-pos: 0px;
  --border-color: hsl(var(--base-h) var(--base-s) var(--base-l) / 1);
  --offset-x: 0px;
  --offset-y: 6px;
  --spread: 0.3rem;
  /* to ensure that the element is sized to have equal size on both
     its block, and inline, axes: */
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  /* a subtle background, I left it in but it's not all that visible: */
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, snow 0 0.5rem, azure 0.5rem 0.75rem);
  border: 2px solid var(--border-color);
  /* defining the block-size of the element, which will influence the
     inline-size via the aspect-ratio property: */
  block-size: 3.5rem;
  display: grid;
  /* using drop-shadow in place of box-shadow, as it's a little more accurate
     (if you remove the background of this element, the visible content of the
     element generates an accurate shadow, whereas box-shadow gives a shadow to
     the outer shape of the element, effectively just a rectangular polygon): */
  filter: drop-shadow(var(--offset-x) var(--offset-y) var(--spread) var(--border-color));
  /* centering the content within the element: */
  place-content: center;
  /* using perspective and translateZ() to move the element somewhat
     faithfully in 3d 'space': */
  transform: perspective(500px) translateZ(var(--base-z-pos));
  /* required to enable any sort of accuracy within the 3d space: */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* defining a transition to apply to every (animatable) property: */
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  /* defining the precise properties to transition: */
  transition-property: transform, filter;
}

/* updating CSS properties for:
   any .labelText element when hovered: */
.labelText:hover,
/* any .labelText element that is immediately preceded
   by an <input> which is in any of the states listed
   within the :is() pseudo-class function: */
input:is(:active, :focus, :checked) + .labelText {
  --base-h: 120deg;
  --base-z-pos: -50px;
}

/* as above, but to specify different properties that
   I didn't want available to the .labelText:hover: */
input:is(:active, :focus, :checked) + .labelText {
  --base-s: 40%;
  --base-l: 60%;
  --base-z-pos: -80px;
}

/* we're hiding the <input>, since we're "replacing" it
   with the <span>: */
input {
  /* scaling it very, very, very small: */
  scale: 0.01;
  /* using absolute position to remove the element from
     the document flow: */
  position: absolute;
}

.error {
  background-color: snow;
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  /* using a large border-radius to have the browser
     style the borders into a 'pill' shape, with
     rounded ends: */
  border-radius: 5rem;
  /* using inset to position the element with reference
     to the containing block, here the 'auto' values
     are equivalent to not setting a property and allowing
     the browser to calculate it, but all values must be
     provided so we have to specify a value; -150% positions
     the pseudo-element's right side 150% outside of the
     containing block. Negative numbers move away from the
     center of the containing block, positive numbers
     move towards the center (on the relevant axis): */
  inset: auto -150% auto auto;
  padding-block: var(--space-s);
  padding-inline: var(--space);
  position: absolute;
  transition: inset 500ms linear;
}

/* :user-invalid matches form-elements that have been given,
   or retained invalid values due to the action/inaction of
   the user; the pseudo-class only matches elements after
   the user attempts to submit the form; with this selector
   we're seleing any .error message within a <fieldset> that
   itself contains an <input> which is invalid following the
   user's attempt to submit the form: */
fieldset:has(input:user-invalid) .error {
  inset: auto 20% auto auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Rhesus Genotype Analyzer</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="/">
    <fieldset>
      <!-- I opted to use an <h2> element to label the grouped elements,
           as a <legend> wouldn't be styled as you seem to wish: -->
      <h2>D</h2>
      <!-- using <label> elements to associate the text, in the nested <span>
           with the <input>, no "for" attribute is required as the relationship
           is implicit due to the <input> being nested within the <label> -->
      <label>
        <!-- the <span> follows the <input> in order to use
             the validity, and user-interactivity, pseudo-
             classes of the <input> to style the adjacent
             <span>: -->
        <input type="radio" value="pos" name="D" required="">
        <span class="labelText">pos</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="neg" name="D">
        <span class="labelText">neg</span>
      </label>
      <!-- using a <span> to contain an error message in the event that the
           user tries to submit an incomplete form: -->
      <span class="error">This field is mandatory, please select one of the options.</span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <h2>C</h2>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="pos" name="C" required="">
        <span class="labelText">pos</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="neg" name="C">
        <span class="labelText">neg</span>
      </label>
      <span class="error">This field is mandatory, please select one of the options.</span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <h2>E</h2>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="pos" name="E" required="">
        <span class="labelText">pos</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="neg" name="E">
        <span class="labelText">neg</span>
      </label>
      <span class="error">This field is mandatory, please select one of the options.</span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <h2>c</h2>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="pos" name="c" required="">
        <span class="labelText">pos</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="neg" name="c">
        <span class="labelText">neg</span>
      </label>
      <span class="error">This field is mandatory, please select one of the options.</span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <h2>e</h2>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="pos" name="e" required="">
        <span class="labelText">pos</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="neg" name="e">
        <span class="labelText">neg</span>
      </label>
      <span class="error">This field is mandatory, please select one of the options.</span>
    </fieldset>
    
    <!-- rather than use an <input> to submit the form, I opted to use
         a <button>; the default action of a <button> within a <form> is
         to submit the form, which is why there's no explicit 'submit'
         attribute: -->
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p3r24f0q/).

References:

- [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active).
- [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).
- [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio).
- [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).
- [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).
- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).
- [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
- [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties_and_values).
- [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).
- [`flex-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow).
- [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus).
- [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas).
- [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).
- [`inset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset).
- [`isolation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-end).
- [`min-block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-block-size).
- [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
- [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).
- [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).
- [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
- [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scale).
- [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).
- [`transform-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style).
- [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).
- [`transition-property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property).
- [`:user-invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:user-invalid).
- [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: That's great, thanks! And thanks for providing the list of references.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the `className` of the selected buttons and separate the selected ones by `className`. In this example, I added `active` className to the clicked buttons and showed their background as `green`. When the user clicks on the selected button again, remove the `active` className and set it to default properties.

```js
function setValue(inputId, value, button) {
    document.getElementById(inputId + '_input').value = value;
     
    if(button.className.includes('active')){
        button.className = ('button')
    } 
    else {
        button.className += ' active';
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 35em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.button {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  background-position: 0 90%;
  background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
  background-size: 4px 3px;
  border-radius: 15px 225px 255px 15px 15px 255px 225px 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 15px 28px 25px -18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #41403e;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Neucha, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 23px;
  outline: none;
  padding: .75rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 235ms ease-in-out;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 255px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 225px 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 255px 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px 225px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 2px 8px 8px -5px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 2px, 0);
}

.button:focus {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 2px 8px 4px -6px;
}

.active { /* Added active property here */
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Rhesus Genotype Analyzer</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/">
  <label for="D">D:</label>

  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('D', 'pos', this)">Pos</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('D', 'neg', this)">Neg</button>
  

  <label for="C">C:</label>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('C', 'pos', this)">Pos</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('C', 'neg', this)">Neg</button>
  <br><br>

  <label for="E">E:</label>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('E', 'pos', this)">Pos</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('E', 'neg', this)">Neg</button>
  <br><br>

  <label for="c">c:</label>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('c', 'pos', this)">Pos</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('c', 'neg', this)">Neg</button>
  <br><br>

  <label for="e">e:</label>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('e', 'pos', this)">Pos</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="setValue('e', 'neg', this)">Neg</button>
  <br><br>

  <input type="hidden" id="D_input" name="D">
  <input type="hidden" id="C_input" name="C">
  <input type="hidden" id="E_input" name="E">
  <input type="hidden" id="c_input" name="c">
  <input type="hidden" id="e_input" name="e">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</body>
```

Hope, it's clear and useful